# Histogram word counter in Python

Tags: python

I would like to ask for code review for my Python histogram word counter.

```
# Given a body of text, return a hash table of the frequency of each word.


"""

# I use a hash map as my data structure to create the histogram
# and add words into the dictionary
# if words are not in the dictionary, then I add those word into the dictionary
# final output is that we return the dictionary
"""

# Word Counter

# Given an body of text, return a hash table of the frequency of each word.

# Parameters
# Input: text {String}
# Output: {Hash Table}

# Constraints
# Capital and lower case versions of the same word should be counted is the same word.
# Remove punctuations from all words.
# Time: O(N)
# Space: O(N)
# Where N is the number of characters in the string.


# Examples
# 'The cat and the hat.' --> '{ the: 2, cat: 1, and: 1, hat: 1 }'`
# 'As soon as possible.' --> '{ as: 2, soon: 1, possible: 1 }'`
# 'It's a man, it's a plane, it's superman!' --> '{ its: 3, a: 2, man: 1, plane: 1, superman: 1 }'`


def word_count(sentence):
    word_counter = {}
    wordlist = sentence.lower().split()
    for word in wordlist:
        word = re.sub('[.,:*! ]', '', word)

        if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1
    return word_counter

example = word_count("It's a man, it's a plane, it's superman!")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Several things can be improved in your existing code. First and foremost being, replacing your usage of `re` module. Regex matching is very heavy. You have a defined set of characters being replaced. Use [`str.replace`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/stdtypes#str.replace) or [`str.translate`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/stdtypes#str.translate).

You have provided comments aptly throughout the program. However, you can place them [as docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for the function, including the examples as [`doctest`s](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/doctest). There are several syntaxes to format docstrings. I am mostly aware of epytext and reStructuredText. You can search around for other common formats :).

You'll end up with:

```
"""
Word Counter

Given an body of text, return a hash table of the frequency of each
word.
"""


def word_count(sentence):
    """
    Word Counter

    Given an body of text, return a hash table of the frequency of
    each word.

    ..  warnings::

        - Capital and lower case versions of the same word should be counted

    as the same word.

        - Remove punctuations from all words.

    ..  note::


    Where N is the number of characters in the string.

        - Time: O(N)

        - Space: O(N)

    :Example:

    >>> word_count('The cat and the hat.')
    {'the': 2, 'cat': 1, 'and': 1, 'hat': 1}
    >>> word_count('As soon as possible.')
    {'as': 2, 'soon': 1, 'possible': 1}
    >>> word_count("It's a man, it's a plane, it's superman!")
    {'its': 3, 'a': 2, 'man': 1, 'plane': 1, 'superman': 1}

    :param sentence: Input string
    :type sentence: str

    :return: Returns hash-table of frequence of each word in input
    :rtype: dict
    """

    translate = sentence.maketrans({char: None for char in "'.,:*!"})
    cleaned_words = sentence.lower().translate(translate).split()
    word_counter = {}
    for word in cleaned_words:
        if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1
    return word_counter
```

---

You can also make use of [`collections.counter`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/collections#collections.Counter) which has the same complexity as your current code. However, it also provides a few extra features on the resulting counter object, such as [`most_common`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/collections#collections.Counter.most_common).

---

<sub>The referenced links above are for python-2.7; however all the modules/packages are available in python 3.x</sub>

Comment: Just curious how common/pythonic it is to have docstrings longer than the function itself?

Comment: @BruceWayne For library functions it's quite common. Anything more top-level than that, not so much. But it doesn't hurt. Zen of Python: explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @BruceWayne As an example: http://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boltons/timeutils.html see various function that the module exposes.

Comment: I think that `.translate(None, "'.,:*!")` is more succinct and accomplishes the same thing as using a translation map.

Comment: @jon they changed the behaviour in python 3 for `.translate`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to *hjpotter92*'s answer you can improve your counting using `dict.get()`

```
for word in cleaned_words:
    word_counter[word] = word_counter.get(word, 0) + 1
```

`dict.get(key, default)`checks for the key in dict and returns default in case key is not in dict.
Makes 1 line out of 4 and improves readability quite a bit. For sure using `collections.counter` is also a good approach - but it includes importing another package.

Comment: `dict.get` completely slipped my mind :) That is indeed cleaner than if-else block

Comment: Better yet, use `defaultdict`.

Comment: True, especially for larger lists to count it seems to outperform the `dict.get()` approach. Have to get used to not only using it for `grouping` :)

Answer (score 3):

*hjpotter92* has covered most things but an alternative to *RandomDude's* dict insertion improvement is to use a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_counter = defaultdict(int)
word_counter[word] += 1
```

An attempt to access a non-existent key will automatically initialise it to 0. Possibly a bit clearer than *RandomDude's* but it's a matter of preference.